# Autofill input credentials of a login webpage with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to autofill credentials of login webpage with this JavaScript code but it is not working:

Do you Know what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" target="_top" action="https://www.allianz.pt/area-privada">

    <input id="usuario" name="_58_login" type="text" value="examplelogin" runat="server" />
    <input id="password" name="_58_password" type="password" value="examplepassword" runat="server" />

    <button onclick="Test()" id="btn">Submit</button>

  </form>

  <script>
    function Test() {
      document.getElementById("usuario").value = "examplelogin";
      document.getElementById("password").value = "examplepassword";

      document.forms["formulario"].submit(); //form submission
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

Submitting data to a URL of an HTML document containing a `<form>` will **not** automatically populate the form with the submitted data.

For that to happen, the server the request is being made to would need to dynamically generate the HTML document and **explicitly** copy the data into the form.

You can't (in the general case) make a browser load a third-party page containing data you provide. That would generally involve a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and/or [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack which sites usually defend themselves against.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how can I do this with other code or language? Do you know if it is possible to do this with an API of a password manager?